# smartctl retest bad sectors

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I got a notification today that my drive was going to fail in 24 hours. The 'Reallocated_Sector_Ct' was already around 3000 and it has since risen to over the last few hours 4004. However, I turn my case on its side a few weeks ago, and tried turning it back upright. Since then, the 'Reallocated_Sector_Ct' hasn't risen, even though currently there's a lot of disk activity as I'm tar/zipping my important data to another drive.

I know having a hard disk not being able to read on it's side is a concern, but if placing the hard drive upright seems to fix the issue for the moment, at least I don't have to panic as much.

Is there a way I can run a retest on those "bad sectors", and remark them as good if they pass the test? I'd like to see how many "really" bad sectors there are after a retest with the box upright (of course I'll do this after my backup is complete).

I'm using Debian if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 13):

I can only second the answer from vonbrand. I've seen at least two HDDs die in the past month after going to pre-fail in SMART.

However, your best bet is probably not SMART itself but instead the `badblocks` utility.

You can let `badblocks` read and rewrite the whole disk, thereby forcing your HDD to reallocate pending sectors. This usally works quite well.

If you don't have the time for running `badblocks` (It can take days on bigger disks) you can try to read out the SMART error log (`smartctl -x /dev/<hdd>` and get a list of broken sectors.

You can then use `hdparm` to read the sector:

```
hdparm --read-sector <sector> /dev/<hdd>`
```

If that fails you force a remap using

```
hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --write-sector <sector> /dev/<hdd>`
```

This works quite well (at least for WD-Green drives, can't you tell anything about other drives)

If you have `dmesg` log messages for failed sectors it's even easier.

```
sectors=$(dmesg | grep <hdd> | grep sector | awk '{print $8}')

for s in $sectors; do <hdparm stuff>; done
```

Before mounting the volume again do a forced `fsck`

```
fsck -f -y /dev/<hdd>
```

And assume to have the drive dying on you yesterday!

Good Luck :)

Comment: After 10953 hours of uptime I had my first reallocated sector. Should I start worrying? Also, the command with dmesg shows that I had the problem with sector 306986 but smartctl -l selftest after short self test says LBA_of_first_error is 343292. So which one is correct and is there a way to find out which file was damaged? I am using XFS.

Comment: @soger The discrepancy is because you got a block number in a partition and a drive block number.

Comment: To test the entire drive (each block), the you probably want to use `fsck -f -c -c -y /dev/<hdd>`. Without at least one `-c` (read-only) or two `-c -c` (read-write) then the blocks aren't going to be tested. All fsck does in that case is verify that the existing data is mostly valid. (inodes make sense)

Comment: @AlexisWilke yeah, it's a good thing I started worrying because that hard disk has failed not long after my comment. But I got off with minimal data loss, nothing important.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the machine, and get a replacement disk **now**! Bad sectors in hard disks tend to grow exponentially, massive data loss is inminent.

Comment: The number of bad sectors hasn't grown past 4004 since I re-orientated the disk. I have a feeling this was a temporary issue, as there's been no growth over the last 24 hours.

Comment: OK, it's your data...

Comment: Vonbrand: You were right, the disk failed. I did save the data though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to re-test sectors which the drive has already marked as bad and re-mapped.  That would be "send it back for warranty" territory.  (E.g. theoretically the vendor may have tools that can validate and reset such a drive).